# How can I escape " or ' when it is a variable in ruby or rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I'm building a js file on the backend for future use and need to convert macros into js code.  My `gsub` in the method below was working fine until I had a url with double quotes.  If I have a variable `quote_type = "'"`, how can I interpolate that as an escaped quote? In other words..

`"'"` becomes `"\'"` and `'"'` becomes `'\"'`

Here's my existing method and I just added the `quote_type` variable to try this out.

```
def substitute_timestamp_macro!(string)
  quote_type = string[0]
  string.gsub('[timestamp]', '\' + new Date().getTime() + \'')
end
```

edit:  example string would be `"https://doesntmatter.com/stuff/123;time=[timestamp]?"`

edit 2:  Here is the expected result:
`"https://doesntmatter.com/stuff/123;time=" + new Date().getTime() + "?"`

here is the actual result
`"https://doesntmatter.com/stuff/123;time=' + new Date().getTime() + '?"`

notice in my `gsub` i hard coded an escaped single quote.  I now want to use the variable to match the input quote so if it's single, use single, and if double, use double

Comment: can you show the expected result vs actual result?

Comment: What does "URL with double quotes" mean here?  I see the URL that you added, and do you mean that the double quotes in that URL are in the value and significant?  What do you want to see as the end result of the translation, in terms of quotes.  Can you show a before and after example?

Comment: @maxpleaner please see the edit 2

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I've clarified in my edits. Thx

Comment: The first part of my question was about which double quotes you mean.  Are the double quotes surrounding the example string the double quotes that you mean?  Do those come IN the URL value that you receive, or is there something else that you're asking?

Comment: You might find it's cleaner to do this in JavaScript with `replace()`.

Comment: Ahh @MichaelGaskill.  So I'm writing to a file, and the input is represented as a string.  But the string itself has double and single quotes within.  In the end, this will be set to a variable in js and I'm handling the quoting of the variable separately from the parsing of the actual text.  Does that help?

Comment: @tadman can't do this in js.  We are building files on the backend (through forms) so that the frontend doesn't do anything but load final file.

Comment: Clearly you *can* do this in JavaScript because there's JavaScript in that string you're sending. It's probably safer to do it this way because you won't need to worry about which quotes are used. I'd say `expand("...[timestamp]")` is a safer, more general-purpose approach than what's here unless you have some data that's Rails specific being put in there.

Comment: well... sure, but we are delegating all processing to the backend. Further, the url isn't ours so what happens after we do our stuff is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `%()` to wrap your string:

```
def substitute_timestamp_macro!(string)
  %("#{string}").gsub("[timestamp]", %(" + new Date().getTime() + "))
end
```

Note that this will render a string with escaped double quotes:

```
substitute_timestamp_macro!("https://doesntmatter.com/stuff/123;time=[timestamp]")
=> "\"https://doesntmatter.com/stuff/123;time=\" + new Date().getTime() + \"?\""
```

Which will be interpreted properly when you render this to a buffer:

```
puts substitute_timestamp_macro!("https://doesntmatter.com/stuff/123;time=[timestamp]")
=> "https://doesntmatter.com/stuff/123;time=" + new Date().getTime() + "?"
```

Comment: This works!  I'll have to make some tweaks, but I can see this working for me. Thanks!

Comment: No prob, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The surrounding quote characters of the value determine the behavior of this function, this should fit the bill:

```
def substitute_timestamp_macro!(string)
  quote_type = string[0]
  string.gsub('[timestamp]', "\\#{quote_type} + new Date().getTime() + \\#{quote_type}")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this... unfortunately in my context, the `quote_type` needs to be escaped.  Now that I think about it, perhaps a literal escape would have worked too? `"\\#{quote_type}"`

Comment: I see.  I'll update the answer to be correct in that regard.

Comment: And the literal escape is the most straightforward solution, so that's what I used.  Thanks!